# How to read users from SAP UME

Tags: jco, sap-enterprise-portal

How to establish a connection to SAP EP (portal) from Java application using JCO?

We are able to connect to ABAP system but not able to get more info to establish connection to SAP PORTAL and read UME users.

Comment: Do you have an RFC that returns the ume users? You may want to check this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357075/how-to-connect-to-a-sap-system-using-sapjco3-and-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP does not recommend to use the proprietary RFC protocol for connecting two non-ABAP systems with each other, but to use other standard protocols like HTTPS for this instead.

However, if you would like to use JCo nevertheless, connecting a standalone JCo application to a NetWeaver AS Java instance (like the Enterprise Portal) would then be a so-called extern-to-extern RFC communication. A direct point-to-point communication is not possible via RFC and you will also need a third component, namely a SAP gateway, which serves as a "meeting point" for both RFC communication partners.

Please see the following SAP Notes for the required special configuration steps at each side:

- [SAP Note 1877907 - Support of extern-to-extern RFC communication with
  JCo 3.0](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1877907)
- [SAP Note 1729203 - Support for communication with external
  RFC server](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1729203)
- [SAP Note 1717833 - RFC destinations to support external
  RFC servers](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1717833)

This was only the technical aspect of the RFC communication. Of course, you then need to implement the client side RFC calls and the RFC server side with offering appropriate Remote Function Modules that provide the desired functionality.
I don't think that such an RFM for reading UME users at the NetWeaver AS Java side is already available out-of-the-box.